# Is it possible to prevent Laravel running Model Events when the database is being Seeded?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-seeding

Laravel's seeder runs a variety of Model Events on my models which trigger New Order notification emails, among other things, from the `Product::saved()` Model Event.

This significantly slows down database seeding. Is it possible to detect whether a Seed is being ran and if so, tell Laravel not to run the Model Events?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `WithoutModelEvents` Trait to your seeder

```php
namespace Database\Seeders;

use Illuminate\Database\Console\Seeds\WithoutModelEvents;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    use WithoutModelEvents;

    public function run(): void
    {
        // Silent eloquent queries ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the correct and modern way to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 37):

There are functions on the `Model` class which will allow you to ignore events.

Before using a model to seed, you will need to do something like this...

```
YourModel::flushEventListeners();
```

Comment: This seems not to work with custom events. 

The other solution:
```
// Remove Dispatcher
Model::unsetEventDispatcher()
```

Seems to work in that case.

Comment: This worked (laravel 8). I placed this in the top of seeder->run

Answer (score 27):

I recommend to remove the Dispatcher in this Case from the Eloquent Model.

For example.

```
// Check Dispatcher
Model::getEventDispatcher()

// Remove Dispatcher
Model::unsetEventDispatcher()

// Add Dispatcher
Model::setEventDispatcher(new \Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher);
```